# Sum Values In Two Different Ranges

Tags: excel, vba, sum, named-ranges

I am trying to add values in two separate ranges together that have two rows of data in. An example of what I'm looking for can be found below:

[image]

The code i have so far can be found below.

The first part of macro works perfectly. It allows me to locate the named range from the input into the target cell, copy that named range and then place in the section adjacent to my target cell.

However, I don't know how to use what i already to have, so that when a second input has been added under the original cell in the first part, to sum now the named ranges of both inputs like in the example above.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    '1: FIRST LABEL VALUES
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J6:J7500")) Is Nothing Then
    
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
        If Target = vbnulstring Then Exit Sub
    
        If Target.Column = 10 And Target.Offset(0, -1).Value > 0 Then
            
            'Find Named Range, Go To It and Copy It
            Dim NamedRange As Range
            Dim LabelCode As Range
            Dim name As String
            
            Range("BT2", Range("BT2").End(xlDown)).Select
            Set NamedRange = Selection
            Range("BS2", Range("BS2").End(xlDown)).Select
            Set LabelCode = Selection
            
            name = WorksheetFunction.Index(NamedRange, WorksheetFunction.Match(Target.Value, LabelCode, 0))
            
            Application.GoTo Reference:=ActiveWorkbook.Names(name).name
            
            Selection.Copy

            Target.Offset(-2, 3).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            
            'Apply % To New Numbers
            Dim rng As Range
            Dim myVal As Range

            Set rng = Selection

            For Each myVal In rng
                myVal = myVal.Value * Target.Offset(0, -1).Value
            Next myVal
            
            Target.Select

        End If
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
    End If
    
    
    '2: SUM FIRST LABEL VALUES AND SECOND LABEL VALUES
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J6:J7500")) Is Nothing Then
    
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
        If Target = vbnulstring Then Exit Sub
    
        If Target.Column = 10 And Target.Offset(-1, 0).Value <> "" Then
            
            'Find Named Range, Go To It and Copy It
            Dim NamedRange As Range
            Dim LabelCode As Range
            Dim name1 As String
            Dim name2 As String
            
            Range("BT2", Range("BT2").End(xlDown)).Select
            Set NamedRange = Selection
            Range("BS2", Range("BS2").End(xlDown)).Select
            Set LabelCode = Selection
            
            name1 = WorksheetFunction.Index(NamedRange, WorksheetFunction.Match(Target.Offset(-1, 0).Value, LabelCode, 0))
            
            Application.GoTo Reference:=ActiveWorkbook.Names(name1).name
            
            
            
            'Find Second Named Range And Add It To First Named Range
            name2 = WorksheetFunction.Index(NamedRange, WorksheetFunction.Match(Target.Value, LabelCode, 0))
            
            Application.GoTo Reference:=ActiveWorkbook.Names(name2).name
            
            
            'Add Values Together
            'HOW DO I DO THIS????
            
            
            'Apply % To New Numbers
            Dim rng As Range
            Dim myVal As Range

            Set rng = Selection

            For Each myVal In rng
                myVal = myVal.Value * Target.Offset(0, -1).Value
            Next myVal
            
            Target.Select

        End If
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
    End If

ErrorHandler:
Exit Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if you are aware but you can achieve what you want with Pastespecial `Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd` ?

Comment: What is wrong using a formula for that? Assuming your screenshot starts with A1: Use in A10: `=A2+A6` and copy it down and right and you would have the desired result. I mean that is exactly what Excel's strength is.

Answer (score 2):

If you have named ranges like:

- `Range1` A2:E3
- `Range2` A6:E7
- `Outcome` A10:E11

[image]

Just use an array formula:

```
Range("Outcome").FormulaArray = "=Range1+Range2"
```

or without named ranges:

```
Range("A10:E11").FormulaArray = "=A2:E3+A6:E7"
```